# How do I build artifacts for Openjdk 11 and Openjfx 11 application? (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx, javafx-11

I am actually new to openjfx 11 and i already tried using openjdk and openjfx libraries to compile my project in intellij IDEA . But after I build artifacts for my project, the jar file of my project doesn't executes.

I tried to execute it using cmd and saw this error:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run
>   this application

Already searched lots of forums, but there's no solution I saw for this specific problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing)?

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! . very informative